# Preferred JDK/JRE for ARM

Tags: java, javafx

I am going to develop a JAVA FX GUI in Linux platform.

MY development is going to be in the x86 processor with Ubuntu 16.04 & NetBeans IDE.

my Target Platform which the software going to be ported is ARM processor.
so Please help me in choosing.

1. Which JDK edition to be installed in development machine. So that, while porting in TARGET it should work
2. Which JRE to be installed in Target ARM board.

Comment: stick to Oracle releases, everything else probably is OSS and buggy. Every Oracle standard JDK and JVM will produce bytecode which runs well on every Oracle standard JRE and JVM - period, regardless of the platform or architecture (as long as the requested features are present)

Comment: Yes, and also OpenJDK doesn't include JavaFX.

Comment: ya fine. But for the development purpose, i am using x86 processor with Linux os. but for my target i am going to use ARM. so for that which JDK from ORACLE website will be suitable.so that after my development it should work in target machine also

Comment: You are asking for a recommendation .... which is off-topic.

Comment: i think you should read a bit about how Java works : this language is supposed to be **platform independent**, it doesnt matter and it never did. You also should ask yourself this question : _"i still dont know the very basics of my chosen language ... am i even able to tackle my problem with this language?"_ JavaFX can be a **very** tricky beast, i would'nt recommend it to beginners because you will need somewhat advanced UI development knowledge

Comment: Preach it, specializt!

Comment: @all: thanks for the clarification. Will check it out.

Comment: Hey ... graphical UIs are tricky beasts no matter how you implement them :-)

Comment: Not .... necessarily - some UI frameworks are much easier to use with a much smaller API and some are horribly large but also very powerful. Methinks JFX might be somewhere in-between - too big for beginners and probably a bit too small for hardcore veterans, featurewise